# how to close a winword.exe that runs in the background (Interop was used)

Tags: vb.net

i created a word doc in vb but the problem is each time my button is clicked it opens a new doc. i have tried the following code to terminate it after it fulfilled its 
purpose but nothing seems to work and
 i have search multiple sites but found no answer that helped 
i used interop

my attempts to close the background winword.exe  (objDoc is the the word doc )

```
      objDoc.Close()
        objDoc.Application.Quit()
        objDoc.Application.DDETerminateAll()
        GC.Collect()
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objDoc)
```

and yes i did look at the post on this site about closing interop word applications but its fails so i am open to any new ideas

Comment: this does not work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777422/disposing-of-microsoft-office-interop-word-application i tried it ,dont know what is wrong but my pc may be possessed or in love with word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are closing the objdoc instead of objWord

```
        objDoc.Close()
        objWord.Application.Quit(False)
        objWord = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just kill the process? Not 100% the best way to do it, but at least you'll be sure that word is being closed.

```
 Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("winword")

 For Each p As Process In pProcess
     p.Kill()
 Next
```

Some code i'm personnaly using to work with Word ( occassion : wordcompare on the server)

- Doc = object of the type Interop.Word.Document
- Dim _myApp As Interop.Word.Application = New Interop.Word.Application()
- Dim vk_false As Object = false
- Dim vk_missing As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

  ```
  Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc)
  _myApp.Quit(vk_false, vk_missing, vk_missing);
  Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(_myApp);
  ```

Comment: I thought i had some alternative code aswell. Will try to find it

Comment: thank you and i tried the process kill it failed this is a problem because i had 178 winword.exe open yesterday it will cause major problems with the program if not fixed

Comment: what error are you getting from the code i gave you?

Comment: no errors  but the process still opens and does not close but it was a nice idea i should have thought of it.If nothing works i will have to change my code completely which will be a pain in the rear end

Comment: Do you have written some extra plugin in Word? Or is the word doc being opened from somewhere else? I find it hard to believe that the first piece of code isn't working.

Comment: the word opens in the background ,information is added and then converted to a pdf and saved to share-point ,if i open task-manager and look under process i find a winWord.exe for everytime i clicked the save button i am using a callback and all of the above methods have been tried without success it should have worked  :                     Dim objWord As New Word.Application()
                                                                                         Dim objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add()

Comment: the only other reason may be my layout it needs to closed after it is saved not before so i am going to go look and see what i can do Thank you Svranken il give you the answer because you tried to help me

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and decided to kill process after I close Word, because otherwise if I run my program multiple times(10-15), I had 10-15 WINWORD.EXE processes in Task Manager.
For this purpose I call command prompt after I release objects and kill process via it with this line **Shell("Taskkill /IM WINWORD.exe /F")**.

It looked like

```
        try 
.
.
.
        objDoc.Close()
                objDoc.Application.Quit()
                objDoc.Application.DDETerminateAll()
                GC.Collect()
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(objDoc)

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error: " & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error!")
        End Try      

       Shell("Taskkill /IM WINWORD.exe /F")
```

Comment: thank you i tried it but still nothing works, i am beginning to think my pc is possessed by a demon ,going to burn the thing ...and roast marshmallows over it ... i appreciate the help my layout might just be wrong i am trying to figure out exactly where i should but the kill it must be after the save else il kill the doc with my information unsaved

Comment: Strange, this worked perfect for me.
Yes, you must put this code in the end, or call after you finish your work or you lose your data. Good luck with solution.

Comment: thanks a lot i placed it at the end from the start but nothing works it is strange indeed all the suggested methods and those i tried myself should have worked i dont know what could be the cause of this  but it is a fun challenge so il keep trying thank you