# C# Need to have my code auto open the excel file after download is complete

Tags: c#, savefiledialog

I'm trying to find a way to have the excel file automatically open as soon as it is done downloading. The file is called "ExportAging.xlsx" and the closest I've gotten to the solution is this:

[image]

This is the code I have

```
  private void ExportToExcel()
    {
      try
       {
          SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
          saveDialog.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
          saveDialog.FilterIndex = 1;
          saveDialog.FileName = "ExportAging";
            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
               saveDialog.OpenFile();
            }
        }
      catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
      finally
        {
          excel.Quit();
          workbook = null;
          excel = null;
        }
   }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Im not an expert but maybe one of the classes you are using implements IDisposable, this means you should call Dispose() afterwards. otherwise i dont think its this program (b)locking the file.

Comment: I'd guess you need your `workbook` object to release the file before you open it with the `saveDialog` object.

Comment: I think Meghan is onto something.  Make sure that your workbook.SaveAs method disposes any FileStream that it uses.

Comment: Just replace excel.Quit(); with excel.Visible = true;

Comment: @Slai Please post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit. It worked like a charm.

Comment: BTW excel.Quit(); usually does not close the Excel instance if not disposed properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, no need to close the Excel Application and then reopen it:

```
if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
   excel.Visible = true;
}
```

Another option can be to close the file after saving it:

```
if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
   workbook.SaveAs(saveDialog.FileName);
   workbook.Close(false);
}
```

[Disposing of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777422/disposing-of-microsoft-office-interop-word-application)