# C# - Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.Quit() has not effect

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop

I wrote a small code to convert a word-document to pdf.

```
public static class WordToPDF
{
    public static bool ExportDocumentToPDF(string DocumentFilename, string PDFFilename)
    {
        bool StillRunning = false;
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(DocumentFilename)) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: File " + DocumentFilename + " not found for opening!"); }

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WDApp = WordToPDF.GetWordApplication(out StillRunning);
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Docu = WordToPDF.GetDocument(DocumentFilename, ref WDApp);
        WordToPDF.Word2PDF(ref Docu, PDFFilename);

        Docu.Close();
        Docu = null;

        if (!StillRunning) {
            WDApp.Quit(false);
            //if(WDApp != null) { System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(WDApp); }
            WDApp = null;
            //KillWord();
        }

        return StillRunning;
    }

    private static void KillWord()
    {
        foreach(System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD")) { p.Kill(); }
    }

    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application GetWordApplication(out bool StillRunning)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WDApp = null;

        if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("WINWORD").Count() > 0)
        {
            StillRunning = true;
            return System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application;
        }
        else
        {
            StillRunning = false;
            WDApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            return WDApp;
        }
    }

    private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document GetDocument(string Filename, ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application WDApp)
    {
        if (WDApp == null) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application is not referenced!"); }
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(Filename)) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: File " + Filename + " not found for opening!"); }

        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc = WDApp.Documents.Open(Filename);
            return Doc;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: Unable to open Word document " + Filename + System.Environment.NewLine + "Detailed error message: " + ex.Message); }
    }

    private static void Word2PDF(ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Docu, string OutputFilename)
    {
        try
        {
            Docu.ExportAsFixedFormat(OutputFilename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex) { throw new System.Exception("ERROR: Unable to export Document to PDF file." + System.Environment.NewLine + "Detailed information: " + ex.Message); }
    }
}
```

The conversation works finde, but after the code is finished, in my task manager there is still an process called `WINWORD.EXE *32` which was not there before.

I don't understand that, because in line 13, I quite the Word.Application object. Does anybody know help?

Thanks and regard,
Jan

Comment: One thing I have found is then setting in this case WDApp to null often clears it

Comment: Thank you, but that's not solving my problem. I also close my document first now - has no effect.

Comment: Its possible your code is not picking up the app instance.. Can you confirm its picking up the instance, if its not picking it up that would explain a lot. If you have word already running can you not just keep a reference?

Comment: If my code picks up the instance, it should not close it in the end. Only, if the instance was created in my code, he should clear it in the end.

Comment: It appears you're not closing `Docu`

Comment: That's right, but i corrected that. I'll update my code now...

Comment: Also, have you checked all [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777422/disposing-of-microsoft-office-interop-word-application)?

Comment: I did - I updated my posting, so you can see what i tried...

Comment: Try assign `Docu = null` after closing it.

Comment: Doesn't change anything, if i set `Docu = null;` after closing it.

Comment: Ok, using `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` it's closing word correctly - after hardly one minute ??? - Thank you all.